# Rectangular shape boxes with Green Vertical Lines in it

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, screen

All of sudden, while I was working, my screen got frozen and started showing some rectangular shape boxes with green vertical lines in it. For the first time, when I pressed on power button, it started beeping (3 times or so) continuously. Wait for 3-5 seconds and again started beeping. After half an hour, I again pressed power button. This time it gets boot up and works properly. The Second time when I experienced same rectangular boxes with vertical lines in it, my MacBook got restarted by itself. I don't know what is the issue with it. Sharing the link for image and video reference.

https://we.tl/t-VDJXDxfnS4
[image]

Comment: What model & year of MacBook is it?

Comment: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)